# Is it possible to have multiple conditions in a conditional statement?

Tags: java

I've searched the internet for this answer, but could not find it. Say I had the conditional statement: `totalRooms += bathrooms > 0 ?  bathrooms : totalRooms;` but I wanted to have two or three conditions to check if they were true, or if I wanted to have something like an 'or' operator for the condition. Is that possible to do with Java Conditional Statements?

Comment: yes it can be done.

Comment: Please do a minimum of research prior to asking questions on SO (read [ask]), thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. For example, testing if bathrooms is between `1` and `99` inclusive like

```
totalRooms += bathrooms > 0 && bathrooms < 100 ?  bathrooms : totalRooms;
```

An or would be written the same way, except with `||` (short-circuiting) or `|` (not short-circuiting).

Comment: Oh, I understand. I was made a mistake and thought I had it right. It was just a syntax error, but since I do not use conditional statements very much when programming, I just made a mistake. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible to have multiple conditions chained together with a series of conditional operators, for example

```
totalRooms += bathrooms > 0 ? bathrooms : bedrooms > 0 ? bedrooms : otherRooms;
```

but I seriously don't recommend it.  For ease of readability, I would write the above as

```
if (bathrooms > 0) {
    totalRooms += bathrooms;
} else if (bedrooms > 0) {
    totalRooms += bedrooms;
} else {
    totalRooms += otherRooms;
}
```

which is equivalent.

Another alternative is to use the `&&` (and) and `||` (or) operators in your boolean expression, like

```
totalRooms += (bathrooms > 0 || bedrooms > 0) ? (bathrooms + bedrooms) : otherRooms;
```

The parentheses aren't really necessary, but they help readability.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(ConditionOne && ConditionTwo && ConditionThree)
{
   // Code to execute
}
```

This is an example for Java.

Comment: I think the OP wanted to see how it would work with a ternary operator